# Pass two String array from doinbackground to fragment

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-asynctask

I am trying to pass 2 String[] from doinbackground to fragment where i have RecyclerView. I also tried setter getter method but still no luck

Here is my Fragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_list,container,false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewForFriendList);

            //WANTS TO REPLACE THESE TWO ARRAY WITH WHICH I AM GETTING IN DOINBACKGROUND
            Name=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.left_Drawer_Menu);
            Image=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.user_image);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter=new RecyclerFriendListAdapter(getActivity(),Distance,Image,LastSeen,Name);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



        return view;
    }
```

Here is my AsyncTask Class

```
 protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL(URL_Path);
            connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);

            }
            String completeJSON=stringBuffer.toString();

            JSONArray parentArray=new JSONArray(completeJSON);

            String[] Name=new String[parentArray.length()];
            String[] ImagePath=new String[parentArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i <parentArray.length() ; i++) {
                JSONObject childObject=parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String Fname=childObject.getString("First_Name") ;
                String Lname=childObject.getString("Last_Name") ;

                Name[i]=Fname+" "+Lname;
                ImagePath[i]=childObject.getString("Image");
                Log.d(TAG,"String Arrays "+Name[i]+" "+ ImagePath[i]);

                     //GETTING ALL VALUES IN LOG SUCCESSFULLY 



            }
            return Name;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                connection.disconnect();
                if (reader!=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
    }
```

I am calling AsyncTask Execute Method in Toolbar of Parent Activity Of Fragment

**UPDATE:**

1) As @BryanDunlap Asked for **onPostExecute** (its just implemented,No code inside it) And How to return both arrays to get in Fragment

2) @IrisLouis suggested to implement interface that's how i did with setter and getter but i wasn't work

```
ublic class WrapperClass {

    private String[] Name;
    private String[] ImagePath;

    public String[] getImagePath() {
        return ImagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String[] imagePath) {
        ImagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String[] getName() {

        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String[] name) {
        Name = name;
    }
```

How i set this in AsyncTask

```
                Name[i]=Fname+" "+Lname;
                ImagePath[i]=childObject.getString("Image");
                Log.d(TAG,"String Arrays "+Name[i]+" "+ ImagePath[i]);
                //LOG RETURNS VALUE OF BOTH ARRAYS

                WrapperClass w=new WrapperClass();
                w.setImagePath(ImagePath);
                w.setImagePath(Name);
```

Getting in Fragment in onCreateView

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
                              ....
                              ....
                              ....
    WrapperClass wrapperClass=new WrapperClass();
            String[] Name=wrapperClass.getName();
            String[] ImagePath=wrapperClass.getImagePath();
            Log.d(TAG,Name.toString()+" "+ ImagePath.toString())


             //IT RETURNS NULLS
```

Comment: We're missing some critical information. Where is your onPostExecute() call in your AsyncTask? That's where you should be passing the data returned from doInBackground() to your Fragment.

Comment: @BryanDunlap Like what ?

Comment: Solution for you. Make a interface callback pass data in onPostExcute() and implements in Fragment.

Comment: Do you want get result of AsyncTask in Fragment ?

Comment: I've updated the comment to reflect what's missing. Also, your fragment looks like it's expecting both Name and Image, while you're currently only returning Name from doInBackground()

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the AsyncTask reference, specifically 'Usage'. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @IrisLouis I update Code as you said and implemented interface. I have tried before this but still getting null in fragment.If am wrong can you show me how to make interface for two string arrays

Comment: @Kabir Raz The object WrapperClass  will return null because in Fragment you `new` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for you, can test it.

In class Asynctask make a interface callback results :

```
public class PageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[] results> {

    private Context context;
    private LoaderListener mLoaderListener;

    public PageLoader(Context context, LoaderListener mLoaderListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mLoaderListener = mLoaderListener;
    }

    public interface LoaderListener {
        void onLoadCompleted(String[] results);

        void onLoadFailed();

        void onPreparing();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mLoaderListener.onPreparing();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
         try {
            URL url=new URL(URL_Path);
            connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);

            }
            String completeJSON=stringBuffer.toString();

            JSONArray parentArray=new JSONArray(completeJSON);

            String[] Name=new String[parentArray.length()];
            String[] ImagePath=new String[parentArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i <parentArray.length() ; i++) {
                JSONObject childObject=parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String Fname=childObject.getString("First_Name") ;
                String Lname=childObject.getString("Last_Name") ;

                Name[i]=Fname+" "+Lname;
                ImagePath[i]=childObject.getString("Image");
                Log.d(TAG,"String Arrays "+Name[i]+" "+ ImagePath[i]);

                     //GETTING ALL VALUES IN LOG SUCCESSFULLY 



            }
            return Name;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                connection.disconnect();
                if (reader!=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
        if (results!= null) {
            mLoaderListener.onLoadCompleted(results);
        } else {
            mLoaderListener.onLoadFailed();
        }
    }


}
```

In Activity you execute Asynctask.

In Fragment you must implements LoaderListener and Override three function.

Ex : `YourFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderListener`

You can handle results callback in `onLoadCompleted`

Ex :

```
@Override
public void onLoadCompleted(String[] results){
  //Do something with results
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i will try soon and revert back to you